# Android: How to run service when application is visible?

Tags: service, android

I want a service to run in the background whenever one of a number of the activities in my application is visible.

I'm currently binding to it in a sub-class of `Application`, like so:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
         bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

However, there's no corresponding `onDestroy` method in which to unbind the service. When when the last activity closes, the service continues to run indefinitely.

1. Is this OK as it is? Should I just allow the OS to shut the service down when low on memory?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to do this on a per-activity basis?

Answer (score 0):

It could be very easily done. Bind the service to the foreground activities. As long as the activities are active Android will keep the service going.

When all the activities are unbound the service will die automatically. (services called by onbind will die automatically when all the bind activities are gone). Only when you use onCreate to create a service you should worry about ondestroy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve it - I want the service to be live in the background whenever an activity is visible, and I don't want to repeatedly start/restart during activity transitions. Perhaps I should have phased my question more clearly - I effectively want to 'start' a service in the application context, and 'stop' it when the application is no longer visible. Sub-activities will toggle the service between foregound and backkground when they opt to bind to it.